# GAM(M): "Shape" vs "wiggliness"?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, generalized-additive-model, splines, smoothing

I'm currently going over how to interpret certain terms of a generalized additive mixed model (GAMM). I'm having a hard time differentiating between "shape" and "curvature". Mathematics aside, how does one picture two smooths that, for example, have the same curvature (a.k.a. wiggliness), but different shape, or same shape but different curvature?

Comment: Is there a reason you think there is an important distinction? Wiggliness is the actual term for how curvilinear the spline it is. In terms of what shape it makes up is entirely based off the wiggliness, but its not clear here in what sense you think that matters.

Comment: This question came to me after reading a comment from Gavin on a post where he describes what gam(y ~ s(x, level, bs = 'fs')) does: ..."and that will result in a random smooths that have the same curvature but not the same shape, where curvature has the meaning of second derivative or what we like to call wiggliness."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65662020/how-can-i-implement-random-smooth-with-common-trajectory-and-different-scale-in

Comment: I was originally trying to understand how one translates a hypothesized effect of covariate X on response Y, by group Z, into GAM lingo. I found the post useful, couldn't understand the terms used and how to apply them in a real-life scenario (depth has a different (shape?) effect on fish counts, by site?).

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand, might wiggliness be analogous to the seasonal variation of atmospheric CO2 while the "shape" term is like the hockey-stick appearance of the long-term trend, for example?

Comment: I've posted an answer which hopefully elucidates this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't aware of this distinction before, so I looked through my usual references and found a more clear discussion on this point in Pedersen et al. (2019):

> It is important to note that “similar wiggliness” and “similar shape”
> are two distinct concepts; functions can have very similar wiggliness
> but very different shapes. **Wiggliness measures how quickly a function
> changes across its range, and it is easy to construct two functions
> that differ in shape but have the same wiggliness**. For this paper, we
> consider two functions to have similar shape if the average squared
> distance between the functions is small (assuming the functions have
> been scaled to have a mean value of zero across their ranges). This
> definition is somewhat restricted; for instance, a cyclic function
> would not be considered to have the same shape as a phase-shifted
> version of the same function, nor would two normal distributions with
> the same mean but different standard deviations. The benefit of this
> definition of shape, however, is that it is straightforward to
> translate into penalties akin to those described in the section “A
> Review of Generalized Additive Models.” Figure 4, model S illustrates
> the case where models have different shapes. Similarly, **two curves
> could have very similar overall shape, but differ in their wiggliness.**

As best as I can tell from this description, a wiggly smooth simply oscillates more, while it's shape is simply where the smooth is fit. For example, an S-shaped smooth and a U-shaped smooth can have very similar wiggliness, while two S-shaped smooths can have radically different wiggliness. To illustrate, here I fit the same data with two functions, one is parsimonious (fits a single bend in the curve) whereas the second is very wiggly because it is allowed to oscillate a lot between the data points. We can see that the shape is similar (some kind of U-shaped smooth here), but the wiggliness is not.

[image]

The below two plots are different in that their shape is different (one looks like a straight line while the other is curved), but their wiggliness is the same (both have a large number of knots, $k = 30$, with a very low smoothing parameter of $\lambda = .001$):

[image]

##### References

Pedersen, E. J., Miller, D. L., Simpson, G. L., & Ross, N. (2019). Hierarchical generalized additive models in ecology: An introduction with mgcv. PeerJ, 7, e6876. https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj.6876